Validity of Approximating a Poisson Mixture with a Simple Poisson
Edited:
I'm considering using a simple Poisson distribution to model a process where the instantaneous rate of events, denoted by $\lambda$, is not constant. Instead, $\lambda$ depends on the current state of a complex underlying system with many interacting factors that change rapidly over time.
Due to the complexity of the system, I'm exploring the possibility of approximating the process with a simple Poisson distribution, where the rate parameter $\lambda$ is set to the time-averaged mean, $\mu_\pi$, of the fluctuating instantaneous rate. My primary concern is understanding how the timescale of fluctuations in $\lambda$ affects to this approximation.
While I don't have a precise model for the dynamics of the underlying system, I know that the factors influencing $\lambda$ change many times during the entire duration of the process, providing a good sample of the distribution of instantaneous rates. However, I'm unsure whether the number of these changes between successive events also plays a crucial role.
Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how the frequency/celerity of $\lambda$ fluctuations between successive events affects the accuracy of the simple Poisson approximation. If
$\lambda$ fluctuates many times during the entire process (thus providing a good sample of the distribution of instantaneous rates, which I denote as $\pi$), but relatively few times between successive events, does this impact the quality of the poisson approximation?
According to Wikipedia (link to Mixed Poisson distribution), the variance of a mixed Poisson distribution is given by: $\operatorname{Var}(X)  = \mu_\pi+\sigma_\pi^2$ where $\mu_\pi$ and $\sigma_\pi^{2}$ are the mean and variance of $\pi$, respectively. Based on this formula, one might expect the variance of the mixed process to approach this theoretical value as long as there are enough fluctuations of $\lambda$ to provide a good sample of $\pi$, regardless of whether there are many or few fluctuations between individual events. However, I performed some numerical simulations that seem to suggest that the frequency of fluctuations also plays a significant role in the variance (maybe some mistake in my code?).
It seems that the approximation systematically overestimate the variance,  are there other biases introduced?

A Poisson mixture will have larger variance, maybe netter to approximate with a negative binomial?

@kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you very much for your suggestion. Approximating with a negative binomial distribution might indeed be more accurate in terms of capturing the increased variance. However, my primary interest lies in understanding, at a conceptual level (I'm not a mathematician), the effect (if any) that the timescale of fluctuations in  λ has on the validity of the simple Poisson approximation. This is because I'm trying to connect the statistical model to an underlying physical process where the rate parameter is influenced by external factors that change over time.

For a better probability of a useful answer, please include those motivations as an edit to the post (only as a comment as ofnow very few people will see it)

This is unclear.  Are you saying that the rate parameters for the mixture parts vary over time?  If so, are you likewise updating your approximation over time?

@Ben Thanks. In my case, the instantaneous rate of events (λ) is influenced by many factors that change rapidly over time. I don't have a precise model for these dynamics, but I know they lead to fluctuations in λ. I'm exploring whether a simple Poisson with a constant rate (equal to the time-averaged mean of λ) can be a valid approximation. My main concern is whether the frequency of fluctuations in λ, relative to the time between events, affects the accuracy of this approximation, even if there are many fluctuations overall. I've edited the question to better reflect this.
